# Windows phone app crashes on launch when using the MvvmCross template

Tags: windows-phone, mvvmcross

I'm using the supplied "MvvmCross.WindowsPhone" template from within Visual Studio.
After making all the required changes, when you try and launch the app in the emulator - it just opens and then immediately crashes.

Comment: Originally it was what was causing the phone app to crash - the answer to which I subsequently found. Thought I'd post here to make Stuart aware, and help out other MvvmCross users. Is there a more appropriate forum to do this?

Comment: Okay, thought that would have been it.  Welcome to SO, btw.  We're cranky, and have a high standard for how things should be handled (for more info on why we're jerks, visit [meta]).  Answering your own question in order to share knowledge is great, and appreciated.  However, you still need to *ask* a question up here, then *answer* that question below.  May seem odd, but that's how we swing.  So, if you could [edit] your question to turn it into an actual question (e.g., "MVVM cross template blows up, wat do") then add the answer below, that would be awesome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly -when a win phone app exibits this behaviour - check the project properties - startup object. If this isn't set, then when the app launches it can't find what class it must use to initialize the app.
In this case, the startup object wasn't set, but there was nothing in the dropdown, even though there was an App file in the project.

I eventually pinned it down to the App.xaml that isn't marked with a build action of "ApplicationDefinition". (resulting in the startup object in project properties being blank.)

Unfortunately setting the correct build action didn't solve the problem.
Only when I set a different project as startup, and then moved back to the windows phone project, did the compilation work again.

Hopefully the template will be updated to set the correct build action for the App.xaml file.